# printing multiple crystal reports in client side with just a click, which are formed in server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I am working on a web application which requires printing multiple reports which are  generated in the server on runtime and in the client side the users can either view the reports or print the reports generated without viewing them. The reports are generated using Crystal reports. I am stuck with the part where I can print the report without loading the crystal report viewer in the client side.
I have gone through a lot of solutions proposed in stakeoverflow but I have not been able to workout a solution for printing the report in local printer (client side) while the file resides in the server side.

Comment: What have you tried that did not work? Which other solutions did you try, and why did they not work in your situation? Post some code and it will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Most solutions like this that I've seen involve a file share for the data files, and the client accessing the file through those shares.